# How to call google recaptcha multiple times on same page and in a single form

Tags: recaptcha

I want load google recaptcha on page load and load another one when user click on reply button.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call:

```
grecaptcha.reset();
```

from Javascript in order to reset the captcha. So, you could do something like this:

```html
<script>

  function reply()
  {
    grecaptcha.reset();
    //do whatever else you need on reply
  }

</script>

<button onclick="reply()">Reply</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but my question is how to render two or more recaptcha. one on page load and one on button click.

Comment: This is how you do that. You can't do two /at the same time/.

Comment: This is not correct, you can have multiple recaptchas /at the same time/. You load it once, and render it to multiple elements.

Comment: That certainly never used to work. But this was in 2017, maybe the situation has changed since then.